# Nesting a default dictionary within a default dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, defaultdict

I am attempting to read a csv formatted as such

```
Number,Letter,Color,
1,a,blue,
1,b,green,
1,c,yellow,
```

and get out a nested dictionary like this

```
{
"1":[
    "Letter":["a","b","c"],
    "Color":["blue","green","yellow"]
    ]
}
```

I can get the Number and its associated rows in from the csv but as soon as I try and nest i get AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append', I think im mostly off to the right start

```
result = co.defaultdict(lambda: co.defaultdict(list))
subresult = co.defaultdict(list)

with open(os.path.join(inputdir,tablelist[i])) as f:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
    read = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=csv_headings)

    for line in read:
        subresult = {}
        for j in range(1,len(csv_headings)):
            #result[line[csv_headings[0]]].append(line[csv_headings[j]])
            result[line[csv_headings[0]]].append(subresult[csv_headings[j]].append(line[csv_headings[j]]))
```

Comment: the dict objects does not have `append` method instead use `update` method

Comment: Well, what is the type of **subresult[csv_headings[j]]**?  You didn't give us a reproducible example.  When I try this with my CSV files, I get a key error at j=1, which means that the resulting object, **None** will have to **append** method.  If this is supposed to be a dictionary, then you're still suck, as **append** is not a dictionary method.

Comment: subresult should be a dictionary with lists corresponding to keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting rid of the header line in your file, this works:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))
with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        r = line.strip().split(",")
        number, letter, color = r[:3] 
        d[number]['Letter'].append(letter)
        d[number]['Color'].append(color)

print d
```

## Output

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f3d99f49b90>, {'1': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, 
{'Color': ['blue', 'green', 'yellow'], 'Letter': ['a', 'b', 'c']})})
```

Answer (score 2):

the dict objects does not have append method instead use update method

something like:

```
result[line[csv_headings[0]]].update(subresult[csv_headings[j]].append(line[csv_headings[j]]))
```

for example:

```
In [1]: a ={'a':1}

In [2]: a.append({'b':2})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-02c9b6cd9396> in <module>()
----> 1 a.append({'b':2})

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

In [3]: a.update({'b':2})

In [3]: a
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: I am using a defaultdict which does have the append method if I take out the nested dictionary It works